# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException occurred Error creating context 'spring.root' -- InnerException: Client.OracleException

Tags: c#, spring, oracle, nhibernate

Presently, I am attempting to debug a web application that connects to an oracle database.  When I run the application, I receive the following error:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException occurred
  HResult=-2146232062
  Message=Error creating context 'spring.root': 
  Source=System.Configuration
  BareMessage=Error creating context 'spring.root': 
  Line=0
  StackTrace:
     at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
     at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
     at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
     at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
     at System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey)
     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName)
     at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.InitializeContextIfNeeded()
     at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
     at Middleware.Data.Services.ServiceFactory.get_WellService() in C:\Dev\trunk\Middleware\Data\Services\ServiceFactory.cs:line 25
InnerException: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException
     HResult=-2146232832
     Message=Error creating object with name 'NHibernateSessionFactory' defined in 'assembly [Middleware.Data.DomainRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5c61376b85e43767], resource [Middleware.Data.DomainRepository.Persistence.xml] line 15' : Initialization of object failed : 
     Source=Spring.Core
     ObjectName=NHibernateSessionFactory
     ResourceDescription=assembly [Middleware.Data.DomainRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5c61376b85e43767], resource [Middleware.Data.DomainRepository.Persistence.xml] line 15
     StackTrace:
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObject(String name)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectFactoryUtils.ObjectsOfTypeIncludingAncestors(IListableObjectFactory factory, Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
          at Spring.Dao.Support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.DetectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(IListableObjectFactory objectFactory)
          at Spring.Dao.Support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor..ctor(IListableObjectFactory objectFactory)
          at Spring.Dao.Attributes.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor..ctor(IListableObjectFactory objectFactory, Type repositoryAttributeType)
          at Spring.Dao.Attributes.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.set_ObjectFactory(IObjectFactory value)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObject(String name)
          at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
          at Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
          at Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.RegisterObjectPostProcessors(IConfigurableListableObjectFactory objectFactory)
          at Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh()
          at Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext..ctor(XmlApplicationContextArgs args)
          at Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext..ctor(String name, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] configurationLocations)
          at _dynamic_Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext..ctor(Object[] )
          at Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeConstructor.Invoke(Object[] arguments)
          at Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.RootContextInstantiator.InvokeContextConstructor(ConstructorInfo ctor)
          at Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.ContextInstantiator.InstantiateContext()
          at Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parentContext, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources)
          at Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section)
     InnerException: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException
          HResult=-2147467259
          Message=""
          ErrorCode=-2147467259
          StackTrace:
               at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
               at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
               at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
               at Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject.DbProviderWrapper.GetConnection()
               at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
               at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
               at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
               at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
               at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
               at Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject.NewSessionFactory(Configuration config)
               at Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject.AfterPropertiesSet()
               at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InvokeInitMethods(Object target, String name, IConfigurableObjectDefinition definition)
               at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper)
               at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)
          InnerException:
```

From looking at the innermost inner exception, it looks like my app is having difficulty connecting to Oracle.  Here are my connection strings, which I have manually verified work properly using sqlplus.

```
  <add name="MyApp"
   connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=orcl)));User Id=myID;Password=myPassword;"
   providerName="OracleODP-11-2.0" />

<add name="BlenderConnection"
    connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=orcl)));User Id=ppdID;Password=ppdPassword;"
    providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>

<add name="Oracle"
     connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=orcl)));User Id=myID;Password=myPassword;"
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I stopped getting the above exception was to uninstall TeamCity and remove my application's website from IIS Manager.

To be clear, I don't think the problem was with TeamCity--the problem was that I ran a build to deploy my application, which added the website to IIS and caused some sort of conflict to produce the error in my question when I tried to debug my website.

Also, part of the problem was that I was receiving this exception:

```
Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
```

To resolve the above problem, I installed the 32-bit client, but mistakenly installed the one for oracle 12, which in fact I needed Oracle 11g 32-bit client:

```
ODAC121021Xcopy_32bit.zip
```

To fix that problem, I uninstalled the above, and made sure to explicitly uninstall all Oracle.DataAccess.dll 2.121 items from C:\Windows\assembly.  Then I installed the proper Oracle 11g 32-bit client:

```
 ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit.zip
```

Next, I updated this file and ran it:

```
C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\selecthome.bat
```

Then I opened this file:

```
C:\oracle\configure.bat
```

To make sure that it properly had all the values of 2.121.2.0 changed to 2.112.3, and ran the file like this:

```
C:\oracle>configure.bat all ORACLE_HOME true
```

Once this file has executed, all of your machine.config files found in places like C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config should have the version number for Oracle.DataAccess set properly.

But rather than messing around with the above, I instead highly recommend working with the managed .NET client which has fairly recently been released if you can:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Unfortunately, right now I have to work with the unmanaged client.